# how to start 2 animations parallel

Tags: css, css-animations

I try to make an animation effect, **box coming from outside of the container and text appears after that box**.

When I add delay to text animation, it breaks, how to sync the two animations?

Help me, please.
Ask me for more details...

```css
@keyframes animText {
  0% {
        max-width: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    100% {
        max-width: 100%;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
@keyframes animBox {
  0% {
        right: 100%;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    100% {
        right: 0;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
#box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #343434;
  display: flex;
}

.redbox {
  background-color: crimson;
  opacity: 0.95;
  width: 74px;
  height: 74px;
  max-width: 75px;
  flex: 1 0;
  position: relative;
  animation: animBox 2s cubic-bezier(0,0,1,1);
}

p {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 0.75em;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 1 0;
  animation: animText 3s cubic-bezier(0,0,1,1) 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <div class="redbox"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take it bro.

```css
@keyframes animText {
   0% {
        max-width: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    33% {
        max-width: 0%;
        visibility: visible;
    }

    100% {
        max-width: 100%;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}

@keyframes animBox {
  0% {
        right: 100%;
        visibility: hidden;
    }


    100% {
        right: 0;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}

#box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #343434;
  display: flex;
}

.redbox {
  background-color: crimson;
  opacity: 0.95;
  width: 74px;
  height: 74px;
  max-width: 75px;
  flex: 1 0;
  position: relative;
  animation: animBox 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);

}

p {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 0.75em;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 1 0;
  animation: animText 2s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <div class="redbox"></div>
</div>
```